# Splitting singular row by ";;" into multiple separate rows in same column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Currently I am in the middle of trying to split the first row whenever ';;' appears, into a new row located in the Material Description column. The code that led up to this point was:

```
df.loc[df['mask'] == True, ['Material Description']] = ';;' + df['Material Description']
df['Material Description'] = df['Material Description'].str.cat()
df['Material Description'].tolist()
df['Material Description'].str.split(';;')
```

A code I have tried is the manipulation of this one but I cannot seem to work this out.

```
pd.concat([Series(row['var2'], row['var1'].split(','))
            for _, row in a.iterrows()]).reset_index()
```

```
        Material Description
0       Hello;; How are you doing;; This is good   
1
2
```

for desired output:

```
        Material Description
0       Hello
1       How are you doing
2       This is good
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change:

```
df['Material Description'].str.split(';;')
```

to:

```
df1 = (df['Material Description'].str.split(';;', expand=True)
                                 .stack()
                                 .reset_index(drop=True)
                                 .to_frame('Material Description'))
print (df1)
  Material Description
0                Hello
1    How are you doing
2         This is good
```

**Explanation**:

If add `expand=True` to [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) get `DataFrame`, then reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and last some data cleaning by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and for one column `DataFrame` use [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html)

Answer (score 3):

This should split the rows like your output:

```
df['Material Description'].apply(lambda x: x.split(';;')).explode().reset_index().drop(columns='index')
```

output:

```
  Material Description
0                Hello
1    How are you doing
2        This is good
```